# Sum of products on a directed acyclic graph

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, algorithms

Is there a textbook/paper that I can reference for the following problem? I am looking for a concise proof that I can cite.

> Let $G=(V,E)$ be a weighted directed acyclic graph, and consider
> $s,t\in V$. Calculate the sum of products of weights along all $s-t$
> paths.

The solution is a relatively straightforward dynamic programming algorithm, so I believe there must be some text where the proof is discussed. I tried inspecting the DP chapters of standard algorithms texts (CLRS, Dasgupta), but I can't see anything similar.

Comment: The DP chapter of CLRS comes before they've introduced graphs. You might have better luck looking through the exercises in the chapter on graph algorithms.

Comment: This is a standard problem in the core of [Hidden Markov Models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model). A nice exposition is given in Chapter 10 of [Bioinformatics Algorithms](https://www.bioinformaticsalgorithms.org/read-the-book) textbook.

Comment: Also, Chapter 10 material is nicely presented in [these video lectures](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQ-85lQlPqFPnk31Uut2ajVkBvlFmMtdx). The algorithm in question is explained at the end of "The Viterbi Algorithm" part.